# Keep lines before while adding new text

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I've encounter this problem with the C# `Winforms` `richtextboxes` that whenever you add a new string it deletes the previously displayed one and replaces it. I was wondering if there is a property within C# that would allow me to keep the previous string and add the new one below it and keep going that way.

Comment: Show some code that is not working.

Comment: There's nothing to really show. I've just been using the richTextBoxName.Text = "this is a message"; I'm really just asking if there is a property within the .NET framework that allows me to solve this.

Comment: try  `richTextBoxName.Text += "this is a message";`. It will append the text  . **Free advice**: Before starting work you should go through good tutorial on C# :)

Comment: You're replacing the existing text. You need to append it with `+=` instead. This is basic C#, and has nothing to do with `RichTextBox` - if you assign an entirely new value to something, it gets the entirely new value. If you want to add to the existing value, you need to do so by adding.

Comment: I know it's basic c#. I'm still learning. I know that this is the case but as I am new I'm still making stupid mistakes. I'll realise this in the future. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Comment: Unless your RTB has no formatting you must __never__ change the text directly or all formatting will be messed up! You __need__ to you `AppendText `!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic operation in any language and is called
Concatenating or Appending Text.
There are many methods in c# to do this.

```
 richTextBox1.Text = "Iam Line 1. ";

 //If you want to append on the same line then
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Iam also Line 1.";

 //Or if you want to append on to the next line
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Iam Line 2.";

 //Also you can go to the next line simply putting \r (Carriage Return) or \n (New Line) Or \r\n
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n" + "Iam Line 3";
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\r" + "Iam Line 4";
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\r\n" + "Iam Line 5";

 //You can also append using other methods like
 richTextBox1.Text += "\nIam Line 6";
 richTextBox1.Text = string.Concat(richTextBox1.Text, "\nIam Line 7");
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(richTextBox1.Text.Length, "\nIam Line 8");
```

Comment: This will mess up all formatting. Do use `AppendText(..)` instead!